# Mysql session not closed after calling stored procedure using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot 1.5.10 and JPA to access mysql database. I set the following properties in configuration:

spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active = 300;

everything is fine until I begin to call stored procedure. The session in mysql is not closed so after some time the resource is exhausted, and I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
```

The stored procedure call is written like this:

```
@Procedure("refresh_mv_slave_holdings_for_master_fund")
void refreshSlaveProductHoldings(Integer productId);
```

And I call this method by :

```
repo.refreshSlaveProcedureHoldings(100);
```

After each call, the session number increases but never comes back. The stored procedure is called in a @Transactional block. Everything is fine if I use the normal JPA call (generate SQL by the domain definition.)

Thanks for help.